# Prove that the complex function $f(z) =\frac{z}{1+|z|}$ is injective

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove that the complex function $f(z) =\frac{z}{1+|z|}$ is injective and have made the following start.

Assume there exists some $z=x+iy$ and some $w=a+ib$,

Then $f(w) = f(z)$ implies that $w=z$ which would prove that the function is injective.

We have $\frac{w}{1+|w|} = \frac{z}{1+|z|}$

Then $w = z \ \frac{1+|w|}{1+|z|}$.

This is where I struggle to see the next step. I know that I want to prove that $|w| = |z|$ and therefore $1+|w|=1+|z|$ but I can't see how to do this without making premature assumptions.

Furthermore, the question states "prove by using polar co-ordinates or otherwise" but again I'm not sure how this is helpful as far as I can see I will still be in the same position at this step even in polar form.

Any help or advice with this question would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since $1 + |z| > 0$ is a real number, $\arg (\frac{z}{1 + |z|}) = \arg(z)$.

Then, if $f(z) = f(w)$ we have that $\arg (z) = \arg(w)$. Now we only need to prove equality of moduli.

Now we are done because the function $g(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}$ is easily seen to be injective in $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$.

EDIT: further explanation on equality of moduli.

If $|f(z)| = |f(w)|$ then we have

$$ \frac{|z|}{1 + |z|} = \frac{|w|}{1+|w|} \implies |z| + |z| |w| = |w| + |w| |z| \implies |z| = |w|$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I follow the first part about arg(z) = arg(w) but I am unclear as to how we have proven equality of moduli. |z| = |w| implies sqrt(x^2+y^2) = sqrt(a^2+b^2) but how can we show these are equal? Thanks

Comment: @sb122 added an edit explaining this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, this has been very helpful as I spent hours overthinking this question and knew it would be a manipulation like this which I overlooked! 
Finally just a follow up question to this, how would I then show that the image of f(z) is the open disk with radius 1 centred at the origin? Therefore f is a continuous bijection from the complex plane to the open disk, right?

Answer (score 0):

If $\frac{z}{1+|z|}=\frac{w}{1+|w|}$, taking moduli gives $\frac{|z|}{1+|z|}=\frac{|w|}{1+|w|}$. Applying $x\mapsto\frac{x}{1-x}$, $|z|=|w|$. Multiplying the original equation by $1+|z|=1+|w|$ gives $z=w$.

Comment: Thank you. Finally just a follow up question to this, how would I then show that the image of f(z) is the open disk with radius 1 centred at the origin? Therefore f is a continuous bijection from the complex plane to the open disk, right?

Comment: @sb122 Clearly the function is argument-preserving & odd with no pole at $0$, so you need only check it maps $(0,\,\infty)$ to $(0,\,1)$. This is trivial; with that restricted domain the function is $z/(1+z)$, with inverse $f/(1-f)$.